# Align multiple Images Horizontally with FPDF and PHP

Tags: php

I am retrieving my images from mysql database and printing to my PDF using FPDF.My problem is i want my  MemImages to be in one line from left to right and not underneath each other to save space when i print.Can you please help and thank you in advance.My code is below.

```
$resultImage = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DBImage WHERE projectSectionId = '$projectSectionId' AND userId = '$userId' AND date = '$date' AND time = '$time'");

while($runImage = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultImage))
{
$image = $runImage['image'];

if(empty($image)){
 } else {
 $pdf->Ln(2);
 $pdf->MemImage($image);
 $pdf->Ln(2);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the answer and for the sack of another developers who will face the same problem.Here is my answer below.

```
$resultImage = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DBImage WHERE projectSectionId =     '$projectSectionId' AND userId = '$userId' AND date = '$date' AND time = '$time'");

while($runImage = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultImage))
{
$array[] =$runImage;
$image = $runImage['image'];

$image_height = 45;
$image_width = 60;

//get current X and Y
$start_x = $pdf->GetX();
$start_y = $pdf->GetY();

if(empty($image)){
 }else{

// place image and move cursor to proper place. "+ 2" added for buffer
 $pdf->MemImage($runImage['image'],$pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(),$image_width,$image_height);
 $pdf->SetXY($start_x + $image_width + 2, $start_y);

  }

}
```